# is beginElement() broken in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-11

***Does beginElement() work in IE?***

I am using Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7.  Here is the fiddle.  Check the console and you'll see the error.  It works on Chrome.  Yes I did google this, I found no answers about IE 11+.

http://jsfiddle.net/yensjw33/2/

```
var ani = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "animateTransform");
ani.beginElement();
```

Comment: Fails in Firefox also, with `NS_ERROR_FAILURE`.

Comment: It fails in firefox because you can't begin an animation that isn't part of a document I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer 11 *does not* support SMIL animation presently. If you would like us to consider it for a future release, please visit our UserVoice and [vote for the request](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-internet-explorer-platform/suggestions/6509024-svg-animation-elements).

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see in the debugger for `ani`'s methods, it does not.

[image: IE Developer Tools Screenshot]

Comment: From the OP: "Does beginElement() work in IE?" And for some reason I thought I had seen jQuery in the tags. I removed that statement.